# How do I unlock the remaining challenge levels in Peggle for Android?

Tags: android, peggle

When I was looking at my Peggle stats on my Android phone, I saw that I'd completed 30 of 100 challenges ... but when I select Challenges from the main menu, I counted only 40 available. How do I unlock the remaining 60 challenge levels, if that's even possible?

Comment: Are the remainder secret? Or perhaps you need to complete the 10 you have available before unlocking the next 10.

Comment: I suppose it's possible, although that isn't how it works on the 360 (all challenges are unlocked once you complete adventure mode). I'm not sure, but I believe all 40 of these became available at once ... hopefully someone with experience can verify (or better yet, with both experience and documentation).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to an email I got from PopCap Customer Support, you are right - there are only 40 challenges (and 55 levels) available - the listing on the stats is an error that they are planning to fix in an update.

Comment: That makes sense to me. They probably just copied code from one of the other versions and either left the 100 in place assuming they would eventually release the rest of the challenges, or just didn't fix the part that counts the total number of challenges.